# Using gremlin from web interface

Tags: gremlin, arcadedb

I would like to use gremlin, either from your web interface, or from gremlin console.

I have tried the following steps:

- downloaded and unzipped arcadedb-23.7.1.tar.gz
- started the server (from my arcadedb folder) by executing bin/server.sh
- accessed the web page http://192.168.0.48:2480/ from the same machine
- selected gremlin from the box that had said sql

FYI, I did/do not want to use docker or similar, and in any case I am not having trouble getter the server to run.

Having used TinkerGraph before, I am tempted to try to enter graph=TinkerGraph.open()
I try that but of course it does not work since this is not TinkerGraph.  So what do I do?  I also tried entering graph=ArcadeDB.open() but this also does not work.

I would very much aooreciate being told what I need to do to create the graph variable (from which I will proceed with what I learned using TinkerGraph.

Also, I received the following messages when starting the server (but they seem to be just warnings):

- 023-09-08 02:26:20.550 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> Studio web tool available at http://192.168.0.48:2480 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
- WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/home/phil/Downloads/arcadedb/lib/arcadedb-gremlin-23.7.1.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
- WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass

Thanks . . .

Phil

Please see the previous part of my message.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a the ArcadeDB web console, your first step should be to create a database. You can do that directly in that user interface by clicking on the database tab on the left, then clicking the "Create" button at the top. You will then name your database. From there you can go back to the first page where you were trying to enter Gremlin commands, ensuring your new database is the "Current database" and start issuing queries.

As for the log messages you mentioned, they shouldn't affect anything. They have to do with certain libraries (Groovy) not being ready for certain versions of Java. for instance, I see it on Java 11 but not on Java 17.